# Why when passing parameters from one component to another it arrives undefined and then arrives again with the data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

As will be shown below when passing properties from a parent component to a child component my code is executed first before the properties arrive and when trying to do a .map of an Array it returns the error "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')". Why does this happen?

[image: As you can see in the image, first you get undefined values which generates the error in the .map and then you get the properties]

As you can see in the image, first you get undefined values which generates the error in the .map and then you get the properties

Parent component:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import ItemDetail from "./itemDetail";
import '../../App.css';
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

//Component Class
const ItemDetailContainer = () => {
    const [producto, productos] = useState([]);
    const { productId } = useParams();

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('http://localhost:3000/productos/' + productId)
            .then(res=>res.json())
            .then(data=>productos(data))
    }, [productId]);

    console.log(producto);

    return (
        <div className="container">
            <ItemDetail
                nombre={producto.nombre}
                id={producto.id}
                precio={producto.precio}
                category={producto.category}
                imagenes={producto.imagenes}
                ancho={producto.ancho}
                alto={producto.alto} />
        </div>
    )
}

export default ItemDetailContainer;
```

Child component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Card } from 'react-bootstrap';
import ItemCount from '../itemCount';

const ItemDetail = ({ nombre, id, precio, category, imagenes, ancho, alto }) => {

    console.log(imagenes);

    return (
            <div className="row" key={id} id={id}>
                <div className="col-md-6" id="productImage">
                    <div className="carousel-item">
                     {imagenes.map((p) => (
                        <img src={p} className="d-block w-100" alt={nombre} />
                    ))}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="col-md-6 producto">
                    <div className="card">
                        <Card.Body>
                            <Card.Title>{nombre}</Card.Title>
                            <Card.Text>{category}</Card.Text>
                            <Card.Text>${precio}</Card.Text>
                            <ItemCount />
                        </Card.Body>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    );
};

export default ItemDetail;
```

Comment: Because initally, the parameter is an empty object, so the property you are passing in is undefined, but when the data is loaded the state is updated, in turn the param is updated in your child component, and is now defined

Comment: Your initial state is an array and the ItemDetail is properties of an object, I think you should set the initial State to null and after that do some conditional in the parent to show a spinner or not render anything unless that state is an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to only execute if `imagenes` is an array. Personally I would rethink how you are structuring your initial state. Instead of it being an empty array, perhaps make it an object with all of those properties having default values.

```
<div className="carousel-item">
    { Array.isArray(imagenes) && imagenes.map((p) => (
        <img src={p} className="d-block w-100" alt={nombre} />
    ))}
</div>
```